# Check one treeset values contains into another treeset

Tags: java, collections

Actually i want to return true if set1 contains some values(b and d) of set2. If any one value exist in any of the set then it should return true

```
class TreeSetExample{

       public static void main(String[] args){
            TreeSet set1 = new TreeSet();
            TreeSet set2 = new TreeSet();

            set1.add("a");
            set1.add("b");
            set1.add("d");
            set1.add("e");

            set2.add("c");
            set2.add("b");
            set2.add("d");
            set2.add("g");

           boolean b1 = set1.contains(set2);// here i am getting classCastException
       }
    }
```

I know that contains will accept only object not collection. So is there any way to check the values between two treeset.

Comment: Check out  the methods in the Collections class.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)?  Including the inherited methods?

Comment: You have  `Set.containsAll(Collection<?> c);` (derived from the `Collection` interface) but it will return true only if all elements of the collection in parameter are contained in the current `Set` object.

Comment: yeah. But i want to look for particular values instead of looking for all values. @davidxxx

Comment: @Akshay Uttur So edit your question with this requirement

Comment: @davidxxx i have clearly specified the values as b and d. I think my question is right. If i use containsAll then it will return false because all values are not present.

Comment: @AkshayUttur only if it contains "b" and "d" or if they have any element common?

Comment: yeah even for common element also it should give result. @Aominè

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you start by not using raw types and utilize generics:

```
 TreeSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>();
 TreeSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>();
```

Now, you can check if the two sets have some elements in common with:

```
if(!Collections.disjoint(set1,set2)){
   // do logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you It worked. Even thanks for approaching me to follow standard coding

Comment: @AkshayUttur no probs, glad it helped you out ;)

Comment: With `TreeSet`s you only need to be careful to make sure they have the same/compatible comparators.

Answer (score 1):

You have  `Set.containsAll(Collection<?> c);` (derived from the `Collection` interface) but it will return true only if all elements of the collection in parameter are contained in the current `Set` object.

To check if any element is contained you can use stream methods.
Of course you should also use generic types and no raw types as you actually used for your `TreeSet` and that are strongly discouraged to use.

```
TreeSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>();
TreeSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>();

... 
boolean isAnyMatch = set2.stream()
                         .anyMatch(s2 -> set1.contains(s2));

System.out.println(isAnyMatch);
```